# What is the musing in an argumentative essay? How is it different from other hooks?

Tags: essay, introduction

In my composition class, I was told that an essay should start with a hook to catch the reader's attention and show them that the content is intriguing and worth reading. One of the many ways we learned to "hook" our reader is to use the "musing". From what I understood, it is just a thought-provoking reflection.

However, if it is actually just a thought-provoking idea, how is it different from, say, a rhetorical question or a startling statement? What makes it peculiar? What are some examples of the musing?